# Получение электронных писем

Tags: android, java, email

Есть проблема с получением писем с э-мейла на Андроид.

```
public class pop3 {

    static String nike;
    static String mes;

  public static void Messages() throws Exception {

    Properties props = new Properties();

    String host = "pop.yandex.ru";
    String username = "romanzi777@yandex.ru";
    String password = "cybercuba";
    String provider = "pop3";

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
    Store store = session.getStore(provider);
    store.connect(host, username, password);

    Folder inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
    if (inbox == null) {
      Log.e("Mail", "No INBOX");

    }
    inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

    Message[] messages = inbox.getMessages();

    for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {

        Log.e("Mail", "Всего писем:" + messages.length);
        Log.e("Mail", "Message " + (i + 1));

      nike = messages[i].getSubject().toString();

      if (nike.contains("FlyNote:"))
      {
     nike = nike.substring(0, 7);
     mes = messages[i].getContent().toString();

      }
     } 
    inbox.close(false);
    store.close();
   }
```

При обработке данного кода, приложение вылетает.

pop3.Messages();

В консоли (на на Андроиде) всё работает. На Андроиде в лог приходит такое:

**09-23 06:40:23.145: E/AndroidRuntime(324): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.mail.Session**

На строчку:

```
 Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
```

В чём проблема?

Comment: я вот смотрю на вопрос и думаю) пароль реальный что-ли?

Comment: Пожалуйста, выложите нормальный работающий код. А то у меня аналогичная проблема

Answer (score 3):

Есть предположение и очень стойкое, что в коде используется класс или даже пакет, которого попросту нет в Android SDK.

Comment: Да, Mail API в Андроиде нет. Рекомендуется использовать `Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); `

Answer (score 1):

К слову. У меня приложение, собранное для платформы 2.2, при запуске в AVD Android 2.2 API8 выдало аналогичную ошибку. А вот начиная с AVD Android 2.3.3 (API10) - заработало, причем без пересборки самой программки. На живом аппарате с Android 2.2 пока не проверял...

p.s. Хотя это скорее из разряда мистики. ;) Больше походит на конфликт каких-то компонент при сборке, когда Session внешней библиотеки перехлестывается с Session чего-то другого.